# How to style material-ui's card components, there's not much on it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to style material-ui's card components, there's not much on it? There's getMuiTheme on the github page but it names a few customize-able properties but there's nothing about color.

Comment: Did you inspect it to see where the color value is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

You can change colors globally for material-ui by overriding the theme like you say.

```
const myTheme = getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme, {
    palette: {
        primary1Color: "red",
        primary3Color: "blue",
    },
});
```

You mention the `Card` component, with `material-ui` you can override styles on specific elements using the `style` or similar props. for example,

```
<Card style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
    ...
</Card>
```